# How do I auto-increment a alphanumeric string primary key?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Let's say I have table A with an alphanumeric string primary key. The code used to create the table and how the table looks are shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE A 
(
    ID CHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_A PRIMARY KEY (ID)
)
```

```
| ID       | ...      |
| -------- | -------- |
| C000001  | ...      |
| C000002  | ...      |
```

I want to insert a new row into Table A and I don't want to type out `C000003` or `C000004` every time. Is there a way to auto increment this?

I have thought about getting the latest id using

```
select top 1 CustId 
from Customer 
order by CustId desc
```

For splitting, I used `SUBSTRING(ID, 2, 7)`. For joining back, I can use `concat('C', ID + 1)`.

The issue is, if I add one to the numeric portion, it would give me 3 instead of 000003. Is there a way to save the 0's?

I just need help with incrementing.

My current code is like this:

```
declare @lastid varchar(7), @newID varchar(7)
set @lastid = (select top 1 ID from A order by ID desc)
set @newID = SUBSTRING(@lastid, 2, 7)
select CONCAT('C', @newID + 1) -- need help with the increment
```

Any help appreciated

**EDIT 1:**
If the numbers are less than 10 (ie one digit), I can manually add in 0's to fill up the gaps. But if the number has 2 digits or more, I can't do that so I'm thinking of a solution for this.

Comment: If you want to auto-increment, I think you might be better off using a numeric key and generating your alphanumeric ID somewhere else. e.g. `myID = 'C' + RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), ID), 6)` in whatever place you want to see the alphanumeric ID.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I made a new edit to my question but i'll say it here. Your solution works if the number is 1 digit. But if the number has 2 digits or more, it would violate the CHAR(7) constraint of the column.

Comment: Does it? 'C' + RIGHT(..., 6) == 1 + 6 == 7. You'll probably get constraint violations when you hit ID 1000001 (1 million and 1), though, because it will truncate the most significant digits.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment @ZLK. I had some typos and now it works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One word of advice: ***DON'T DO THIS!*** Using this `SELECT MAX() + 1` approach is not safe under load, as soon as more than one user will be using your application, you **WILL HAVE DUPLICATES** - sooner or later.

The only viable solution is to use

- an `ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)` column to get SQL Server to handle the automatic increment of your numeric value
- a **computed, persisted** column to convert that numeric value to the value you need

So try this:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Customer
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
    CustomerID AS 'C' + RIGHT('000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(6)), 6) PERSISTED,
    -- .... your other columns here....
)
```

Now, every time you insert a row into `Customer` without specifying values for `ID` or `CustomerID`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Customer(Col1, Col2, ..., ColN)
VALUES (Val1, Val2, ....., ValN)
```

then SQL Server will **automatically and safely** increase your `ID` value, and `CustomerID` will contain values like `C000001`, `C000002`,...... and so on - automatically, safely, reliably, no duplicates.

Answer (score -1):

I think it's not any suggested way that automatically incrementaly change the char value. By logic we can do. Below is method which is perfect method for achive this effectivly.

Suppose you have one table called stminternal having following column
Code,
Prefix,
Digit,
LastNo

```
Insert into stminternal values(1,'C',6,0)
```

So using this table you can generate new string.
First time
WHEN RECORD INSERT C000001.

```
UPDATE stminternal SET LASTNO=2 WHERE CODE=1
```

Such a way it can be work like charms